# java scanner input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

Can I use the scanner from java to get the output from one class and use it as input for another class? 
I have a JFrame that prints a message like so:

```
if(jButton1.getText().compareTo("SEND")>=0){
        String msg;
        int cod=0;
        if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){ 
            if(jTextField1.getText().length()>=2) cod = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText().substring(0, 2));
            if (codes.get(cod)!=null){
                msg=codes.get(cod).concat(jTextField1.getText().substring(2));
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
            jTextField1.setText("");
        }
        else{
            msg=jTextField1.getText();
            jTextField1.setText("");
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }
```

and a class that uses a scanner to get messages from console:

```
Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MSGS; i++) {
    s = scanIn.nextLine();
    message.setText( "This is message " +s );
    System.out.println("Sending message: " + message.getText());
    producer.send(message);
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? explain a bit, please...

Comment: I want to create a message using the output from the JFrame.

Comment: I don't get it... tell us the scenario in a more detailed way like "I want to take the message from here, send it there, build the message and print it" etc

Comment: I insert a text in a text field and when I press a button I want to create a message with that text in that other class in order to be sent, but so far I am able just to print the text from the Jframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do that in some complicated way but may I suggest just calling a method instead. Let's say you want input from both the console and the other class. Then you can make a method `doSomethingWithInput(String msg)` that is called from both the scanner class and the JFrame.

Comment: Right now the scanner is in the main method and I can not call non static methods from there. I don't want to input from console I want to send the message from the JFrame to the other class but the message may not be ready when the other class needs it or I could be sending many messages and the other class will not get them, that is my problem.

Comment: The non-static method is a non-problem. You can just create an object and call a method from the main method instead (or make the doSomething static as well). I don't really understand your problem though. The messages will always be sent if you call a method - directly when it gets there in the code. I think maybe what you want to look at is threads (but I doubt that's necessary) - so that both the sender and reciever can run concurrently.

Comment: Both the JFrame and the other class run in the same time so i want the message to be created exactly when I type somthing in the JFrames text field.

Comment: why won't you create the message after you press a button?

Comment: you could do something like: when you press the send button, you call a method which has the message as a parameter and on the other side (receiver) you do whatever you want to do with the message